# htaccess rewriting to include file in every folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there a way I could use htaccess' url rewriting feature to look like there's a file in let's say the `/public/some/folder` when it's actually in `/public`.

For example I have index.php in root folder and I want it to be like that when I access index.php then it could also behave as its in all the folders and subfolders too

When I execute index.php then it will also execute in all folders and subfolders too

**Update**

Please understand my question by the example below

index.php is in root and I have different folders in root as well
so when I access the index.php through browser then it will also execute in other folders

`http://example.com/index.php` will also behave as if its in sub folder too

`http://example.com/folder1/index.php`

`http://example.com/folder2/index.php`

`http://example.com/folder3/index.php`

`index.php` is not in these folders but it must execute in these folders too at the same time

I think its not difficult to understand through this example.please answer accordingly

Comment: you mean like index.php?page=category&subcat=tet changes to example.com/category/test ?

Comment: @Soundz NO not changes to but

index.php should behave as if its also in other folders too without uploading index.php manually to each folder
I want to have index.php in main folder only and want to execute it in other folders too at the same time

Comment: in other word, you want to prevent indexing on folders that contains images/files?

Comment: obviously it's XY Problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. But any way you can try something like that in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So after it everything will go to index.php with $_GET[page] parameter. So for example www.mydomen.com/try/to/get/this will go to our index.php where we will have our $_GET[page]="try/to/get/this". If you will use explode for this string you can write any rules you want for you url. Something like your own URL manager :)

example:

put your index.php in the root folder and also .htaccess 
in your index.php:

```
$urlArray = explode("/",$_GET['page']);
switch($urlArray[0]){
  case "try":
     include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/path/to/folder/what/you/need/my.php");
     break;
  case "another_url":
     include($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/another/path/to/folder/what/you/need/my_another.php");
     break;
}
```

Hope it is what you needed.

Comment: This is not what I require.I updated my question by an example please read it and answer accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the way that you need. Can You describe you problem? What do you want to achieve?