# ID in url as login

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom authentication method: in the URL there is a unique ID after slash which is like a login.

When the user passes under the link I need to catch that ID and send it for example to `index.php?url_id=****`.

The URL is like domain.com/*udfgsdfgsd* or domain.com/*urtywerty*.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url_id=$1 [QSA, L]
```

But I'm new to the mod_rewrite and so nothing happens...

P.S.
I also have another `GET (?panel_status=****)` which appears after authorization for navigation and i wondering how to do that the URL after authorization would be like domain.com/some-user-id/some-panel-status or just may be add some prefix to users id like `u_*****` and redirect when there is `u` to `url_id`, in other cases  to panel_status

Comment: Going to ask a hopefully obvious question - what will happen if I log in, then change the URL manually? Will that redirect me to another users details?

Comment: when page with id is loaded - there also is a pin code.

Answer (score 0):

I just described this situation in the answer to this post. Look here:
[htaccess rewriting to include file in every folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050485/htaccess-rewriting-to-include-file-in-every-folder/12051130#12051130)

Comment: mmm... May be something bad with my host? I recive: The requested URL /users/dev/sfgsdfg was not found on this server. when try to add something after slash....

Comment: check your .htaccess with mine pls

Comment: do You use any framework or clear PHP? If just PHP then it might be a server configuration issue

Comment: Only var_dump($_GET['page']); in index.php. May be it because of the subdomain, because in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules()) returns true.

Comment: http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=33868 just to check with subdomains

Comment: I already googled it.... But my mistake - site is located only in sub folder, not subdomain...

Comment: what I can say for now with information what I do have from you :) That error which you get says that it doesn't see .htaccess file. Only what I can to suggest you just Look better in your folder structure and to be sure that your htaccess file lays exactly in the folder where you go from the web. Sorry.....